# Python evaluation of compound statement as if condition

Tags: python

I'm have trouble understanding the evaluation order of statements that are if statement conditions:

assume I have a dictionary like this, that maps words to a list of webpages:

```
index = { WORD, [url1,url2,url3] }
```

When inserting into this index there are two cases:

1) The key (WORD) does not exist in the index already, you need to create a list and set WORD as a
key in the map

2) The key (WORD) exists in the index already, I just need to append the current url to the list already in the dictionary

What I expected to work:

```
def update_index(word, url):
    if word in index and not(url in index[word]):
       index[word].append(url) # list already exists append to it
    else: 
       index[word] = [url] # new list with url as a single element
```

This however only every allows 1 url per word.

What did work:

```
def update_index(word, url):
    if word in index:                  # <- isnt having two consecutive if statements 
                                       # the same as an AND???
       if not(url in index[word]):
          index[word].append(url) # list already exists append to it
    else: 
       index[word] = [url] # new list with url as a single element
```

Any help clearing this up would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show example inputs / data structure layouts and outputs. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Try using a `defaultdict` with a `set` instead of a regular `dict` with a `list`.

Comment: @Marcin This is the relevant part of my application that I am asking about. The full application is too large to reasonably post here.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen If you don't want people to be able to tell what's wrong, then go ahead and ignore my advice.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Marcin wasn't asking for the entire application, he was asking for a small sample bit of code that someone could copy and paste into the interpreter for testing.  I had to write a test case myself to check my solution (but mgilson ninja'd me, darn him to heck).

Comment: @DSM -- I don't appreciate being darned to heck.  I hear it isn't very nice there. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're definitely different (since you have an `else` clause).  In the first case, you enter `else` clause in the event that your dictionary has the key, and the element is already in the list (which you probably don't want).

In other words, when the `url` is already in the list, you replace the list with `[url]` instead of just doing nothing.

Comment: Phew -- I almost missed this one.  Sometimes these little logic things can be tricky ...

Comment: Thanks, totally blanked out and missed that.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen -- I sat there blinking at it for a minute thinking "There has to be something wrong someplace else in the code ..."

Answer (score 2):

To understand the logic problem, look at the other answers.  But as I said in the comments, you can end-run the whole problem with:

```
from collections import defaultdict

url_store = defaultdict(set)
url_store[word].add(url)
```

Comment: This is good advice (but only if a set is an appropriate container for the urls to live in, which depends critically on the rest of the problem).  The uniqueness constraint on the list makes `defaultdict(list)` much less worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah, I chose `set` specifically because of the `not(url in index[word])` clause in his code.  If he wanted to track duplicates, it should be `defaultdict(list)` and `url_store[word].append(url)`.

Comment: it's clear he doesn't want duplicates.  However, order might still matter (in which case a `set` is not appropriate).

Comment: True order could matter, but he doesn't say so, and if it does, he doesn't specify if the order to preserve is first-seen or last-seen.  At this point though, we are talking about almost pure conjecture without OP specifying.  :)

Comment: True.  Like I said in my original comment, this is good advice provided that there aren't other constraints rendering a set unusable.  I even upvoted because I like it so much :^).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you always overwrite the entire list of URLs whenever you find a URL that's already in the list.

Your condition checks whether the word is in the index *and* whether the URL is not yet in the list for that word. So if the word is in the index, and the URL is already in the list, the entire condition evaluates to false and the else-case is executed, overwriting the existing list for that word with a list holding only the duplicate URL.

Instead, you should try this:

```
if word not in index:
    index[word] = [] # create new empty list for word
# now we know that a list exists -> append
if url not in index[word]:
    index[word].append(url)
```

If you use a `defaultdict`, as suggested in another answer, the `defaultdict` will do this check (the first `if`-statement) for you.

*Update:* Got the composite if-condition wrong myself...  First paragraph is now fixed.